# Скорость итерации по std::vector и std::list

Tags: c++

Просто для интереса решил сравнить скорость итерации по вектору и листу с доставанием значения из каждого элемента с присвоением другой переменной:

```
#include <iostream>           
#include <list> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <vector> 
#include <string> 

int main()
{

    std::list<std::string>my_list_string_1;
    std::vector<std::string>my_vector_string_1;

    my_list_string_1.push_back("1");
    my_list_string_1.push_back("2");
    my_list_string_1.push_back("3");
    my_list_string_1.push_back("4");
    my_list_string_1.push_back("5");
    my_list_string_1.push_back("6");
    my_list_string_1.push_back("7");
    my_list_string_1.push_back("8");
    my_list_string_1.push_back("9");
    my_list_string_1.push_back("10");

    

    my_vector_string_1.push_back("1");
    my_vector_string_1.push_back("2");
    my_vector_string_1.push_back("3");
    my_vector_string_1.push_back("4");
    my_vector_string_1.push_back("5");
    my_vector_string_1.push_back("6");
    my_vector_string_1.push_back("7");
    my_vector_string_1.push_back("8");
    my_vector_string_1.push_back("9");
    my_vector_string_1.push_back("10");


int clock1;
    int clock2;

    size_t cntr = 9999999;


    std::string my_string_list_temp;
    std::string my_string_vector_temp;


    
    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cntr; i++)
    {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            my_string_vector_temp = my_vector_string_1[y];
        }
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << my_string_vector_temp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "time_vector_string:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    



    
    std::list<std::string>::iterator list_iter;
    list_iter = my_list_string_1.begin();

    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cntr; i++)
    {
        list_iter = my_list_string_1.begin();
        for (size_t y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            my_string_list_temp = *list_iter;
            list_iter++;
        }
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << my_string_list_temp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "time_list_string:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
```

Результаты на x86, release, VS2019:   (мерял по отдельности, комментируя секцию вектора и листа)

-вектор: 866 мс

-лист:   742 мс

Результаты на x64, release, VS2019:   (мерял по отдельности, комментируя секцию вектора и листа)

-вектор: 615 мс

-лист:   613 мс

Подскажите, почему данный код на x86 работает быстрей для листа, а на x64 разницы нет ?

Comment: меня смущает, что у Вас получилось, что вектор медленнее.  Вот люди заморачиваются посерьезнее https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/11/cpp-benchmark-vector-vs-list.html

Comment: плюс ко всему, Вы тестируете разные способы. Для вектора - доступ по индексу, для списка - просто итератор. Делайте для вектора итератор. Также, 10 элементов это не тот размер, на котором можно хоть как то потестировать. ну хотя бы 10к.

Comment: Попробовал потестить этот код, у меня результаты вышили другие - 64 - vec 819 list 843, 32 - vec 3922 list 4235. Хотя тоже использовалась VS2019. Удивительно, что 32 битный вариант настолько медленее. Также надо сказать, что тут меряется итерация по совсем коротким контейнерам, где оверхед от перекладывания дополнительных указателей списка не заметен.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, при кол-ве элементов от 1 млн, разница сразу видна в строну вектора.

Comment: @user7860670, странно, почему тогда у меня такие результаты ? Это может зависить от версии Windows ? У меня 10ка.

Comment: Ну и у меня тоже. Может процессоры очень сильно различаются? У меня Xeon E3-1245 v6.

Comment: @user7860670, i5-9600.  Даже не думал, что для такой простой операции может влиять различия в процессорах.

Comment: учитывая это  "мерял по отдельности, комментируя секцию вектора и листа" возможно, тестируется один и  тот же код. тогда результат предсказуем

Comment: @KoVadim, не совсем понял. Почему один и тот же код ? Но даже, если бы и один и тот же код, то и время было бы одинаковое.

Comment: у Вас время отличает незначительно. +-10% это обычно стандартная ситуация в "домашних наколенных тестах". Хорошие бенчмарки это сложно. Поэтому, я предполагаю, что у Вас тестируется один и тот же код (например, потому что не перекомпилируется)

Comment: @KoVadim, неее, ну как это :)   Если бы код не перекомпилировался при закоментаривании одной секции, то на консоль выдоилось бы два значения времени или ожно и тоже, а выводится то только одно или cout<<time_LIST_string или time_VECTOR_string. Это Вы загнули про "не перекомпилируется" :)

Comment: а я не видел, как тест делается. поэтому не могу ничего сказать на эту тему. К тому же user7860670 получил немного другие результаты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

посмотрел внимательно на это все и есть такие мысли. Их конечно лучше подкрепить кодом от ассемблера.

что такое итерация по списку с точки зрения ассемблера? это к заданному адресу добавить небольшое смещение (4 или 8), что бы взять адрес указателя на следующий елемент и прочитать с него значение. Все. Если список маленький и локальный (то есть, весь в кеше), этот процесс очень быстрый. Так как Вы много-много раз бегаете по одному и тому же списку, то он с второй итерации скорее всего весь и будет в кеше.

в 64битном режиме студия генерит вот такое - очень кратко:)

```
mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbx]
```

что такое итерация по вектору/массиву? это вычисление по формуле начало массива + индекс * размер элемента. Обычно реализуется одной командой LEA, которая эффективна, когда размер элемента кратен 2, 4 или 8.  Но в примере в коде это std::string, который обычно 24 или 32 байта (насколько я знаю, стандарт не требует определенного размера) и придется умножать ручками. А это уже немного сложнее.

Если посмотреть в код, то компилятор в 64битном режиме оказался хитрее, и просто к текущему адресу плюсует 32

```
add     rbx, 32
```

то есть, в 64битном режиме на самом деле бенчмаркаем mov vs add. Контейнеры? не не слышали:)

а что же в 32битном режиме? для списка студия сделала так

```
mov     esi, DWORD PTR [esi]
```

не очень и отличается. просто регистры другие.

для вектора

```
add     esi, 24
```

других явных отличий я не увидел. Код который перекладывает строку в переменную явно потребляет большую часть времени цикла.

Почему же такие результаты? да ничего необычного. Хотелось потестировать скорость итерации по контейнерам, а по факту тестировалась разница в mov/add на фоне вызова конструктора копирования строки.